# how to seperate agents based on their attributes (if attributes are assigned in a table)

Tags: java, database, anylogic, agent

I have made a table with columns[date,name,sex,and age] and linked this to an agent. I want to separate the agents with a specific name(attribute) to specific block using select output box. I have created name as a parameter for the agent from the table. But when I try to put condition in select output block ((Person)agent).name == "ahmed" or agent.name=="ahmed" no conditions went true and all are bypassed to false port.

[image: please refer to all details in image].

I have also tried to declare the variable in an agent and tried to pass it in select_output but the same result.
I am able to print the names of the agent using traceln(agent.name) in the action box. BUT in the condition it's not working... any help would be great thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For text comparisons, you need to use `.equals()` as it compares the contents of the string, whereas `==` compares if they are the same object

So you should use `((Person)agent).name.equals("ahmed")` this will give you true if the name of the agent is "ahmed"

You can read more [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/string-comparison-in-java)